# Is there an SFML delta mouse movement event?

Tags: c++, mouseevent, sfml

I'm trying to implement a way to click and drag the screen in SFML. The idea being that when the user clicks down on their mouse, an `sf::View` gets changed by how much the user moves their mouse until they release it.

I tried to use the `sf::Event::MouseMoveEvent` struct under the assumption it would give the mouse movement and not the position. When I used it in code, however, it gets the position.

I could try and keep track of the previous mouse position and subtract it out to get the change, but I would expect that there would be a struct or function that would give me the delta position. It has this functionality for the scroll wheel, so I'd hope it does for the mouse.

Comment: I do not completely understand your requirement, but if you want to have the delta, why don't you store the previous position and calculate the delta?

Comment: I did eventually end up storing the previous position like you suggest, but the problem I had with it is that it put in a lot of questions about implementation details that would be solved if there was a delta mouse position function. For example, where in the code do I store the previous position? If I store it along with the ```sf::View``` then I might have to implement it again if I need the delta somewhere else. Or if I make it static, whatever delta I calculate might change during what time I get it, because the previous mouse position has to be updated at some point etc.